# DataProtection - Share machine key between multiple applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Let's suppose that we have two APIs, one for `UserManagement` and one for `Auth`.

`UserManagement API` is responsible for initial invitation email (where i need a `ResetPasswordToken` because this is my current app flow) and `Auth API` is responsible for password recovery (where i need a `ResetPasswordToken`).

Of course, i need to specify the same machine key for both applications.

Let's also suppose that those two applications will be deployed behind a load balancer. 2 apps x 3 instances.

It is sufficient to have the same shared location for persisting keys (Redis or so) in both APIs?

```
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToRedis(/* */);
```

I'm thinking that if it works for one app, multiple instances scenario, it will work for multiple apps, multiple instances scenario too.

P.S: I wasn't able to find anything about any locking mechanism (it seems that there is one just looking at how it behaves)

Another thing that i'm concerned of: race condition?!

> Duc_Thuan_Nguy Jun 9, 2017
>
> Out of curiosity, how does key rolling
>   handle concurrency? For example, let's say we have a web-farm with 2
>   machines and a shared network directory. There may be a race condition
>   in which both machines want to roll a new key at the same time. How is
>   this situation handled? Or the two machines can roll their own new
>   keys and as long as they can have access to both new keys, they can
>   unprotect data smoothly?

Comment reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-management

**Later edit:** It looks like if you have multiple apps it isn't sufficient to specify that you want to persist keys in the same location. There is a concept of application discriminator (all apps being isolated).

You will need something like the following:

```
services.AddDataProtection(configure => {
                configure.ApplicationDiscriminator = "App.X";
            }).PersistKeysToRedis(/* */);
```

Locking and race condition questions are still valid.

Comment: Its typical of your using a load balancer to ensure that the servers behind the load balancer have the same machine key configured on the server. You want each sever to essentially be identical

Comment: Virgin github ticket about the race condition issue: https://github.com/wpbrown/oakproxy/issues/52

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it's not sufficient. ASP.NET Core's data protection isolates applications by default based on file paths, or IIS hosting information, so multiple apps can share a single keyring, but still not be able to read each other's data.

As the [docs state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?tabs=aspnetcore2x#setapplicationname)

> By default, the Data Protection system isolates apps from one another,
>   even if they're sharing the same physical key repository. This
>   prevents the apps from understanding each other's protected payloads.
>   To share protected payloads between two apps, use SetApplicationName
>   with the same value for each app

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName("shared app name");
}
```

Comment: Considering that both apis are using the same application name, do we need to be worried about which one is going to generate the key? Or if there are any race condition issues?

Comment: No we tested that by hacking the key validity period to a minute and ran 50 VMs 

Comment: It would certainly be a welcome addition to the docs to explicitly state that race conditions are not a concern, as I'm sure many developers are worried about having a "master" instance of their application that is solely responsible for generating keys.

Comment: @Ian Why are the race conditions not concern? How ASP.NET Core resolve the conflict?

Comment: @kogoia - I don't know, that's why I said it would be nice if MS told us so.

Comment: @Ian I found an answer. Race condition not actual because new key generated each time, there is no change (update) old key. Append only. But we have another problem here. When app1 generate new key another instance refresh it not immediately. This causes that some requests will not be handled, because app2 can't decrypt cookies encrypted with new key

Answer (score 0):

A quick update on this one: it seems like it's possible to eliminate race conditions by using the `DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration` method on all of your apps except the "main" one.

i.e. it will be

```
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName("shared app name");
```

for the main one and

```
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName("shared app name")
        .DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration();
```

for all other apps